# Binding only one column

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

Setting text property of Tabs as follows:

In the code below , GetQuesType() returns a complete QuesType named Table so the Tabs generated by the code below are like equal to the no. of records in the table.
What I want is that ONLY QuesType column be binded to the Tabs. What should I change in my code?

aspx page:

```
**<div id="div1" runat="server">
        <telerik:RadTabStrip ID="RadTabStrip1" runat="server" MultiPageID="RadMultiPage1">
        </telerik:RadTabStrip>
        <telerik:RadMultiPage ID="RadMultiPage1" runat="server" Width="100%">
            <telerik:RadPageView ID="pv1" runat="server" Selected="true">

            </telerik:RadPageView>
        </telerik:RadMultiPage>
    </div>**
```

I have followed this example:

http://mono.telerik.com/TabStrip/Examples/PopulatingWithData/DynamicCreation/DefaultCS.aspx

{EDIT}

Modified the method as follows:

```
private void CreateRootTab(DataSet ds)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            var tab = new RadTab();
            tab.Text = (string) ds.Tables[0].Rows["QuesType"].ItemArray[i];//PROBLEM AREA
            RadTabStrip1.Tabs.Add(tab);
        }
    }
```

**Now it says:
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.DataRowCollection.this[int]' has some invalid arguments**

How else should I bind the tabs with QuesType column?

ok it should have been this:

```
tab.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["QuesType"].ItemArray[i].ToString();
```

Now its giving error on itemArray

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'ItemArray' and no extension method 'ItemArray' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You should probably rename the title to something like "Error when referencing members of an object in the DataColumn of a DataRow". This question doesn't really have anything to do with data binding. On a positive note, you did provide a very detailed description of your problem. Bravo! Double-bravo for using Telerik components! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default type returned by a row column is `Object`. You need to cast the column returned by this statement...

```
ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["QuesType"]
```

...to the appropriate type before calling `ItemArray[0]`. A quick and dirty way to do this is...

```
tab.Text = ((QuesType)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["QuesType"]).ItemArray[0];
```

However, a more robust, and less error-prone solution would be...

```
if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
{
    var table = ds.Tables[0];
    var columnName = "QuesType";
    if (table.Rows.Count > 0 && table.Columns.Contains(columnName))
    {
        var tableRow = table.Rows[0];
        var quesType = tableRow.Field<QuesType>(columnName);
        if (quesType != null && quesType.ItemArray.Count() > 0)
        {
            tab.Text = quesType.ItemArray[0];
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that helps!